# How to finetune an already Finetuned Llama 2?

Tags: large-language-model, huggingface, llama, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I finetuned a Llama2 7b model using huggingface interface for sagemaker, but I want to finetune the model again on a another dataset. Is this possible? I looked around a lot, but have not found anything in this regard.